# Espaço em branco em Expressão Regular

Tags: java, regex

Com a seguinte expressão regular **(^DOC)*[0-9]** consigo capturar todos os números após o a sequencia "DOC". Porém, ao testar nesse texto :

**TEXTO TEXTO TEXTO TEXTO DOCUMENTO:240010 24/09/2014**

ele me retorna "24001024092014", a data vem junto. A dúvida é, como consigo pegar a sequencia numérica, e caso encontre um espaço, ele não inclua no regex ? Gostaria de capturar apenas o numero do documento.

Segue codigo java:

```
public class Teste {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        String CAPTURAR_SOMENTE_NUMEROS_APOS_PALAVRA_DOC = "(^DOC)*\\d+ ";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(CAPTURAR_SOMENTE_NUMEROS_APOS_PALAVRA_DOC);

        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("TEXTO TEXTO TEXTO TEXTO DOCUMENTOLEGAL:240010 24/09/2014 ");

        while(matcher.find()){
            System.out.printf(matcher.group());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Qual o código que você está usando para aplicar essa regex? `matches`, `lookingAt`, `find`... P.S. Você tem certeza que essa regex funciona? No meu entendimento, `(^DOC)*` significa "A sequência 'DOC' no início da linha, zero ou mais vezes", e `[0-9]` significa "um único dígito".

Comment: Sim funciona. Encontrei uma outra forma utilizando a seguinte ER : "(^DOC)*\\d+ ", porém ele me retorna junto com o espaço. Eu sou leigo em expressão regular. Preciso estuda-lo melhor

Comment: O que eu quero dizer é que esse `(^DOC)*` é irrelevante, você poderia substituir sua regex inteira por `[0-9]` e você continuaria tendo o mesmo resultado (experimente sua regex original com `TEXTO TEXTO 123 TEXTO TEXTO DOCUMENTO:240010 24/09/2014`, ele vai pegar o `123` **antes** do `DOC` também). Da mesma forma, sua segunda sugestão pode ser substituída por `\\d+` e mais nada. Se quiser que eu explique melhor, por favor poste o trecho de código Java que você está usando para aplicar essa regex a uma string.

Comment: Verdade !! Se puder tirar essa dúvida pra mim, ficarei grato mgibsonbr.

Comment: Coloquei uma resposta. Infelizmente não conheço nenhum bom tutorial de regex em português pra te indicar, mas se você clicar na tag [tag:regex] e em "Saiba mais..." ou "info" você encontra algumas referências úteis sobre o assunto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O método [`Matcher.find`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) procura por ocorrências de uma expressão regular em uma string. Ou seja, ela retorna qualquer substring que case com a regex que você está procurando. Se você quer extrair o número que está logo à frente de um `DOC`, existem duas maneiras: grupos de captura e *lookarounds*.

### Grupos de Captura

O método de grupos de captura é o mais simples, como [demonstrado na resposta do Rodrigo Rigotti](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/34015/215): você estabelece o texto que você quer casar, e entre parênteses coloca os subtextos que te interessam mais. Exemplo simples:

```
DOCUMENTO:([0-9]+)
DOCUMENTO:(\d+)
```

Isso pega a string `DOCUMENTO:` e qualquer sequência de números que a segue, e mais nada. A sequência de números - estando dentro de um grupo de caputra - pode ser acessada através do método [`group(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28int%29):

```
matcher.find();
System.out.printf(matcher.group(0)); // Pega o primeiro (no caso, o único) grupo de captura
```

Se você tem alguma variância na palavra `DOCUMENTO` - por exemplo aceitando tanto `DOCUMENTO` quanto `DOC` - você pode marcar o sufixo como **opcional** (através do operador `?`):

```
DOC(UMENTO)?:(\d+)
```

Mas note que, ao fazer isso, você criou um novo grupo de captura - que será o grupo zero, e os números que você quer serão o grupo um. Se você quer evitar que o primeiro grupo seja capturado, você pode usar `(?:regex)` em vez de `(regex)`:

```
DOC(?:UMENTO)?:(\d+)
```

Por fim, se você tem outras entradas possíveis - como no seu exemplo, `DOCUMENTOLEGAL` - você pode ajustar a regex de acordo, ou mesmo aceitar qualquer sequência de letras depois de `DOC`:

```
DOC\w*:(\d+)
```

Apenas tome cuidado para não casar mais do que você quer (`\w` aceita qualquer letra, número ou underscore; `regex*` aceita zero ou mais ocorrências de `regex`).

### *Lookarounds*

Os [*lookarounds*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) são partes da regex que são verificadas, mas não entram no resultado final. Um *lookahead* tenta casar trechos à frente, enquanto um *lookbehind* tenta casar trechos atrás. Por vezes essa técnica é útil, mas ela é por demais complicada (e não funciona igualmente em todas as implementações de expressões regulares), de modo que eu sugiro evitá-la quando possível. A título de exemplo, sua expressão ficaria dessa forma:

```
(?<=DOCUMENTO:)\d+
```

Ou seja: "pegue uma sequência de números, mas verifique se essa sequência é precedida de `DOCUMENTO:` sem incluir no casamento". A desvantagem dessa técnica é que não é qualquer coisa que se pode ser colocada num *lookbehing* - em particular, muitas implementações exigem que a regex tenha tamanho fixo. O que no seu caso é um problema, pois você precisa verificar tanto por `DOC` quanto por `DOCUMENTO`, etc...

Comment: Sensacional !! Valeu pela breve e rica explicação !! Você tem razão. Talvez eu tenha entendido errado o conceito de REGEX, porém, acho que consigo resolver o meu problema parcialmente. Obrigado !

Answer (score 1):

Uma sugestão:

```
DOCUMENTO:(\d+)\s*(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)
```

Exemplo de implementação:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexMatches
{
    public static void main(String args[]) {

      String line = "TEXTO TEXTO TEXTO TEXTO DOCUMENTO:240010 24/09/2014";
      String pattern = "DOCUMENTO:(\d+)\s*(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)";

      Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

      Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
      if (m.find( )) {
         System.out.println(m.group(0) + m.group(1) + m.group(2) + m.group(3));
      } else {
         System.out.println("Sem resultados.");
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Sua regex está boa, mas a ideia do AP é **não** incluir a data no resultado, i.e. você pode ignorar os grupos 1, 2 e 3.

Comment: Rodrigo, muito bom sua dica, obrigado !! Porém, eu coloquei somente "DOC" na ER pois o texto pode vir tanto "DOC" quanto "DOCUMENTO", então a idéia é pegar tudo que é número após a sequencia "DOC" até encontrar um espaço. No caso (^DOC)*(\d+)\s*(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+) resolveria meu problema ?

Comment: @AlexandreHideki Eu não sei o que você acha que `(^DOC)*` faz, mas a maneira correta de fazer isso que você pede é `DOC(UMENTO)?:` - i.e. "a sequência 'DOC', seguida ou não de 'UMENTO', seguida de dois pontos".

Comment: Como não tive muito tempo para pesquisar e estudar regex, a principio achei q (^DOC)* faria com q o regex encontrasse esta sequencia, negasse a mesma, e pegasse valores definidos por mim a partir dela. Porém, vc me mostrou ali em cima que ela é irrelevante, pois, eu não havia testado o regex com numeros antes da palavra DOC. A conclusão que cheguei ao executar pela primeira vez e ele me trazer somente os números, é que estava correto !

Comment: @AlexandreHideki Existe um tipo de verificação de padrão chamado [**glob**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29), muito usado em sistemas de arquivo e coisas assim. Provavelmente foi isso que você achou que expressões regulares eram. Mas na verdade, regex é uma linguagem totalmente diferente... :)

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] vetor = texto.split((^DOC)*[0-9]\\S);
```

O vetor resultante terá duas posições: vetor[0]= 240010 e vetor[1]= 24092014, só basta pegar o vetor[0] que a parte que lhe interessa.